# Remove front characters from a string?

Tags: c#, .net, string, split, c#-2.0

What is the best way to remove a few characters from the beginning of a string?

```
sName = "IMG: Testing again"  
sName = "TXT: This is amazing"
```

So remove IMG: and TXT.. etc...

So I can have this?

```
sName = "Testing again"   
sName = "This is amazing"
```

Comment: What have you tried? [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: Do you have a list of prefixes to be removed?

Comment: You really should try Googling it first, this kind of questions have been asked a million times before, and should not be asked again here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if its always gonna be four characters you could do. `sName = sName.Substring(5)`

Comment: Will that remove the first three characters and keep the rest?

Comment: first four characters it starts at zero but yes

Comment: This removes the first 3 characters, not the first 4.

Comment: Not to mention that the user wants to remove the space as well, so you should be using `sName.Substring(5)` to get the the results in the OP's example.

Comment: @RyanSchlueter:  The argument is `startIndex` - the first one that is **included**.  OP is right - this wil remove the first three characters because you're starting at the fourth.

Answer (score 1):

I personally like a simple [regular expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312.aspx) for tasks like this.

```
var result = Regex.Replace(input, @"^[A-Z]+:\s*", "");
```

This has slightly different semantics than the other methods presented in what it will remove, so here the match is explained (also refer to the [regular expression quick reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx)).

```
^         # anchor match to start of input
[A-Z]+    # match one or more capital English-alphabet characters
:         # match a colon
\s*       # match zero or more spaces
```

As such this approach also match input like "HELLOWORLDILOVEYOU:said Fred" and get rid of extra leading spaces in "TXT:       Wut?".

Comment: @zimdanen Except not - [I'm not solving nqueens](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=297616) ;)

Comment: yikes, that looks like fun.

Comment: @zimdanen I can't even grasp how the author started down such madness! I agree that regular expressions can be overused though, and I've seen some bad perversions. I generally feel safe if 1) there is no more appropriate existing parsing tool; 2) I can fit the regular expression construct on a single line; and 3) I can understand it the next day without needing to refer to notes.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you always use the format `{TYPE}: {Text}`, and you want the `{Text}`, use this:

```
int index = sName.IndexOf(':') + 2; // two:  one for the colon and one for the space
sName = sName.Substring(index);
```

This can, of course, be put into one line; I have it broken into two for clarity.

You can also make an extension method for the general case:

```
public static string SubstringAfter(this string str, string sequence)
{
    int index = str.IndexOf(sequence);
    if (index > -1)
    {
        return str.Substring(str.IndexOf(sequence) + sequence.Length);
    }
    return str;
}
```

This lets you do this:

```
sName = sName.SubstringAfter(": ");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 sName = sName.Remove(0,5); //simple but not perfect way
```

Edited:

```
 sName= sName.Split(':')[1]; //For splitting by ':'
 sName = sName.Remove(0,1); //For the space, or use sName.Trim();
```

Comment: This only removes the first 3 characters, in the examples given the  user wants to remove the first 5 characters (including the space).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to go for a split if its a fixed format. See the code. After splitting the 1st index will have your item.

```
var sName = sName.Split( new char[] {':'})[1].Trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
sName = sName.SubString(4, sname.Length)
```

It will a substring from the 4th position to the last position of the string.